# Show that if $(x_k)$ and $(y_k)$ are sequences in $V$ such that $x_k \to x$ and $y_k \to y$, then $x_k + y_k \to x + y$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space. Show that if $(x_k)$ and $(y_k)$ are sequences in $V$ such that $x_k \to x$ and $y_k \to y$, then $x_k + y_k \to x + y$.

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x+y$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t $B(x+y, \varepsilon) \subset U$. Since $x_k \to x$ there is a $n_0 > 0$ such that $x_k \in B(x, \varepsilon/2)$, whenever $k \ge n_0$. Similarly there exists a $m_0 > 0$ such that $y_k \in B(y, \varepsilon/2)$ whenever $k \ge m_0$. Now I’m not sure if I should pick $k_0 = \max(n_0, m_0)$ or $k_0 = \min(n_0, m_0)$ to make this work?

I have that $$\|(x_k + y_k) -(x+y) \| = \|(x_k - x) + (y_k - y) \| \le \|x_k - x \| + \|y_k - y \| \le \varepsilon$$ when $k \ge k_0$?

Comment: Pick the max. Why???

Comment: If I pick the max how can I be sure that either one of the sequences don’t end up being outside the neighborhood?

Comment: Quantum space explains. Picking the max, the bigger of the 2 numbers $n_0, m_0$ , both $x_k,$ and $y_k$ (all of the terms)$\ge k_0$ are in the respective balls. OK?

Comment: You do this exactly the way you do it if $V=\Bbb R$ and if $\|u-v\|=|u-v|$. Just change the notation from $\Bbb R$ to $V$, and from $|u-v|$ to $\|u-v\|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use open neighborhoods and stuff like that. Simply observe that
$$\|x_n + y_n -(x+y)\| = \|(x_n-x) + (y_n-y)\| \leq \|x_n-x\| + \|y_n-y\|$$
for all $n$. Letting $n \to \infty$, we obtain
$$\lim_n \|x_n + y_n-(x+y)\|= 0$$
which means that $\lim_n (x_n + y_n) = x+y$.

---

Nevertheless, your proof is correct if you consider the maximum. Why the maximum, you may ask? Well, if $k \ge k_0$, you have $k \geq n_0$ AND $k \geq m_0$ so both terms become smaller than $\epsilon/2$.  If you would have taken the minimum, you won't be able to garantuee that both terms become smaller than $\epsilon/2$, but rather only one of them.